# Android HttpPost without parameter name

Tags: android, http-post

[image: Image to post request using]

I've used POST methods many times in the past but got this weird web service. It works fine on a chrome extension but i am unable to get this response using android .  Please add anything in the code if missing

Here is the code i am using

```
              HttpParams param = new BasicHttpParams();
            param.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(param);
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            Utils.showLogs(MyConstants.TAG, "ApplicationURL: " + url);

            httppost.setHeader("Content-type", contentType);
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(param, MyConstants.WEBSERVICE_TIMEOUT);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(param, MyConstants.WEBSERVICE_TIMEOUT);

            String response = null;
            try {
                if (jsonObject == null) {
                    StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(json, HTTP.UTF_8);
                    httppost.setEntity(entity);
                } else {
                    StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(jsonObject.toString());
                    httppost.setEntity(stringEntity);

                }
                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                final int statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                    return MyConstants.SERVER_NOT_RESPONDING;
                }
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
```

Thanks

Comment: Please explain more about the problem, you receive an error? Logcat? If you debug the code enter in if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK)?

Comment: i am getting response but its {"Message":"An error has occurred."} . Its server error 500.

Comment: Van you access server log or write some log to inspect a major details on this error?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in `AndroidManifest.xml` ?

If not, add this should be fine!